# How to set background color in a chart in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

The question self explains itself. [Here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart.html) is the link that I'm following.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

what is with chart.set_chartarea() or chart.set_plotarea()?

See the following links:

- http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart.html#set_plotarea
- http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart.html#set_chartarea

Regards

Answer (score 2):

For Changing the background colors of the plot area and chart area, the 'set_plotarea()`and`set_chartarea()` on the chart object will need to be called with the appropriate color.

For filling the background colors of the bar charts, key value like `'fill':{'color':'yellow'}` while adding the series on the chart object should do.

For example:

```
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5','fill':{'color': 'yellow'}})
```